# PHPOffice/PhpSpreadsheet: Reset cell style

Tags: php, phpexcel, phpspreadsheet

In the docs

- https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/develop/
- https://phpoffice.github.io/PhpSpreadsheet/master/PhpOffice.html

i didn't find any useful function for my need.

Is it possible to "reset" / "delete the entire formatting" of a single cell? Return the cell to its original state.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

explicitly undoing the previous format should work:

```
$ws->getStyle('A1')->applyFromArray(array(
    'font' => array('bold' => false)
));
```

when importing, one can also skip formats altogether: `$reader->setReadDataOnly(true);`

Comment: I had already tried the first approach (and it does not work). The second approach works, but i was hoping for something more efficient. Thank you

Comment: @WhiteLine ever tried to pass empty sub-arrays, eg. `'font' => array()`?

Comment: Yes, doesn't work. The only approach is the second one. Using the "NONE" property, for example : FILL_NONE for FILL property, BORDER_NONE for BORDER property, etc etc..

Answer (score 0):

Instead of "undoing" all of your previous style changes, you can duplicate a cell style (that you didn't change) to your desired reset cell/range.

> @param string $range Range of cells (i.e. "A1:B10"), or just one cell (i.e. "A1")

```php
function resetStyle(\PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Worksheet\Worksheet $worksheet, string $range): void
{
    $worksheet->duplicateStyle(
        $worksheet->getStyle('ZZ99999'),
        $range
    );
}
```